# The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction when trying to make Bus.SendLocal in Handler (local Azure worker)

Tags: c#, azure, transactions, handler, nservicebus4

I have a next code:

```
class ProcessHandler : IHandleMessages<StartProcess>
{
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }

    public void Handle(StartProcess message)
    {
        //some long living process (over 3 min)

        Bus.SendLocal(new SameMessage()); //get error here
    }
}
```

error message: The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.

stack trace:

*at System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistVolatile(InternalTransaction tx, IEnlistmentNotification enlistmentNotification, EnlistmentOptions enlistmentOptions, Transaction atomicTransaction)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistVolatile(IEnlistmentNotification enlistmentNotification, EnlistmentOptions enlistmentOptions)
   at NServiceBus.Azure.Transports.WindowsAzureStorageQueues.AzureMessageQueueSender.Send(TransportMessage message, Address address) in c:\BuildAgent\work\ba77a0c29cee2af1\src\NServiceBus.Azure.Transports.WindowsAzureStorageQueues\AzureMessageQueueSender.cs:line 51
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.SendMessage(List`1 addresses, String correlationId, MessageIntentEnum messageIntent, Object[] messages) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.SendMessage(Address address, String correlationId, MessageIntentEnum messageIntent, Object[] messages) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.Send(Address address, Object[] messages) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.SendLocal(Object[] messages) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.SendLocal(Object message) in :line 0
   at Amira.Merger.WorkerRole.Handlers.ProcessTPGFilesHandler.SaveToDataBase(TourML tourMLObj) in d:\AmiraProject\SourcesOfAmira-Tour\Amira\Amira.Merger.WorkerRole\Handlers\ProcessTPGFilesHandler.cs:line 161
   at Amira.Merger.WorkerRole.Handlers.ProcessTPGFilesHandler.DeserializeAndSaveData() in d:\AmiraProject\SourcesOfAmira-Tour\Amira\Amira.Merger.WorkerRole\Handlers\ProcessTPGFilesHandler.cs:line 139
   at Amira.Merger.WorkerRole.Handlers.ProcessTPGFilesHandler.Handle(StartProcessTPGFiles message) in d:\AmiraProject\SourcesOfAmira-Tour\Amira\Amira.Merger.WorkerRole\Handlers\ProcessTPGFilesHandler.cs:line 122
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object )
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.HandlerInvocationCache.Invoke(Object handler, Object message, Dictionary`2 dictionary) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.HandlerInvocationCache.InvokeHandle(Object handler, Object message) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.Behaviors.LoadedMessageHandlers.b_*2(Object handlerInstance, Object message) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.Behaviors.InvokeHandlersBehavior.DispatchMessageToHandlersBasedOnType(IBuilder builder, LogicalMessage toHandle, LoadedMessageHandlers loadedHandlers, BehaviorContext context) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.Behaviors.InvokeHandlersBehavior.Invoke(BehaviorContext context, Action next) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain.InvokeNext(BehaviorContext context) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain.<>c*_DisplayClass1.b_*0() in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Sagas.SagaPersistenceBehavior.Invoke(BehaviorContext context, Action next) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain.InvokeNext(BehaviorContext context) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain.<>c*_DisplayClass1.b_*0() in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.Behaviors.LoadHandlersBehavior.Invoke(BehaviorContext context, Action next) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain.InvokeNext(BehaviorContext context) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain.<>c*_DisplayClass1.b_*0() in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.Behaviors.CallbackInvocationBehavior.Invoke(BehaviorContext context, Action next) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain.InvokeNext(BehaviorContext context) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain.<>c*_DisplayClass1.b_*0() in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.Behaviors.ApplyIncomingMessageMutatorsBehavior.Invoke(BehaviorContext context, Action next) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain.InvokeNext(BehaviorContext context) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain.<>c*_DisplayClass1.b_*0() in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.Behaviors.ExtractLogicalMessagesBehavior.Invoke(BehaviorContext context, Action next) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain.InvokeNext(BehaviorContext context) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain.<>c*_DisplayClass1.b_*0() in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.Behaviors.RaiseMessageReceivedBehavior.Invoke(BehaviorContext context, Action next) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain.InvokeNext(BehaviorContext context) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain.<>c*_DisplayClass1.b_*0() in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.Behaviors.ApplyIncomingTransportMessageMutatorsBehavior.Invoke(BehaviorContext context, Action next) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain.InvokeNext(BehaviorContext context) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain.<>c*_DisplayClass1.b__0() in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.UnitOfWork.UnitOfWorkBehavior.Invoke(BehaviorContext context, Action next) in :line 0*

can some one help me with this?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nsb handlers is surrounded by a system.transactionscope. You can change the default timeout in app.config in the system.transaction-section. There is a transaction setting in the Nsb fluent config; Configure.Transactions.Advanced, there may be a timeout setting there as well.

The maxtimeout is 10 minutes, if youre operation is taking than that, you have to change this in machine.config (have to do this on a Startup-task).

Hth

//Peter